# Randomize Image On Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, drag-and-drop

I need some help on my App

https://jsfiddle.net/fdatm462/1/

This is what I am working on currently

I am using Jquery Mobile as well for my framework and I have a feature that refreshes my page when i click a button in my navbar

```
<li><button onclick="location.reload(true)" class ="ui-btn-b">New Cakes</button></li>
```

I also have different images of cakes such as the one you see in the fiddle
how do i get it to randomly display different images and take a different answer on page refresh, I am more worried aboutt how to get it to randomly display first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need a list of images that you would select from:

```
imgArray = [ "img1.png", "img2.png", ... ];
```

To select a random element from the array you can use `Math.random()` to select a value from 0 to 1 (excluding 1), and multiply that by the length of your array to get from `0` to `n-1`, and finally taking the floor will make it an integer.

```
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*imgArray.length);
randomImg = imgArray[randomIndex];
```

Then you can change the `src` to your random image by doing:

```
$("#source li img").attr("src", randomImg );
```

Comment: may you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: @artbarzz Sure, [here is a general example](http://jsfiddle.net/9echs4xe/). And [here is an example with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/fdatm462/2/). You only have a single provided image, so I used some template ones.

Comment: wow spencer thanks so much for the help, it works amazingly, now i am just trying to figure out how to make it so lets say it displays 0 it goes into its correct location on the droppable options , can i use the index that stores the random image variable into here?  $('#answerfour').droppable({
                accept: 'li[data-value="four"]',
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $('#four').append(ui.draggable);
                }
            });